# Android HttpURLConnection UnknownHostException

Tags: android, http, исключения

Пытаюсь подключиться к валидному и доступному (через десктопный и мобильный браузер) хосту  
http://ichannelmedia.str.com_melody.s3.amazonaws.com/JSC_Portal_Parentals_Final.pdf  
И получаю UnknownHostException  
В манифесте, естественно, разрешения на интернет добавлены.  
Не могу понять "то ли лыжи не едут..."  
Прошу помощи...

Подключаюсь так:

```
URL url = new URL(u);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```

Добавлю еще стактрейс:

```
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: http://ichannelmedia.str.com_melody.s3.amazonaws.com/JSC_Portal_Parentals_Final.pdf
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:279)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.ichannel.android.ui.activities.PDFActivity.downloadFile(PDFActivity.java:81)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.ichannel.android.ui.activities.PDFActivity$1.doInBackground(PDFActivity.java:38)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at com.ichannel.android.ui.activities.PDFActivity$1.doInBackground(PDFActivity.java:32)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Где

```
08-04 16:56:15.591  23840-24053/com.janssen.android W/System.err﹕ at     com.ichannel.android.ui.activities.PDFActivity.downloadFile(PDFActivity.java:81)
```

и есть строчка

```
connection.connect();
```

Comment: Скорее всего okhttp не может подключиться из-за .pdf в конце ссылки. Попробуйте подключиться к другому URL и посмотреть, будет ли работать приложение. Вариант 2: уберите "http://" из ссылки.

Comment: @SuperCreeper есть подозрение, что это связано с большим кол-вом субдоменов в УРЛе    
вот такая ссылка нормально работает    
http://s3.amazonaws.com/ichannelmedia.str.com_melody/5794-JSCScorecard%E2%80%93June2014.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемой оказалось слишком большое число субдоменов в УРЛе. Не знаю, почему существует ограничение такого рода, но ссылка вида  
http://s3.amazonaws.com/ichannelmedia.str.com_melody/5794-JSCScorecard%E2%80%93June2014.pdf  
работает правильно